# Photosynthesis in oxygen free enviornment

Tags: photosynthesis

If a plant is grown in an oxygen free enviornment would it live longer in light or darkness?

It is evident that oxygen would compete with carbon dioxide during various processes like competing with carbon dioxide for reducing power, also oxygen quenches the excited electron of chlorophyll etc.

But all these effects to me don't give any sense of the extent of oxygen on these reactions. What does the absense of oxygen have on the system? Except ofcourse the plant not being able to respire properly.

Comment: So, what's your doubt here? Plants are dependent on oxygenic respiration for ATP because they evolved that way.

Comment: My doubt is which environment would the plant live longer, in light or in darkness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that "environment" is a closed vessel or bell-jar; certainly the plant would survive in light (when it simultaneously perform respiration and photosynthesis), and in darkness (when it can perform only the respiration) it would survive upto certain time due to the oxygen it accumulated. But should die at prolonged darkness when the plant would finish all the oxygen.

(as suggested by [Priestley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Priestley)'s classic 1870 experiment `*` there was enough oxygen to keep a mouse for certain time)

[image: mouse, belljar]

(image [link](https://classconnection.s3.amazonaws.com/863/flashcards/5206863/png/priestley_experiment_2-14652524CF75C0692D6.png))

---

However, if we look the **effect of various concentration of O<sub>2</sub> on photosynthesis rate** without altering the CO<sub>2</sub> concentration; yes the photosynthesis rate get affected; one known effect is called [Warburg effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warburg_effect) or Inhibition of photosynthesis by O<sub>2</sub>.

In this effect, photosynthesis rate only decrease if O<sub>2</sub> concentration is increased. And in vice-versa, with O<sub>2</sub> concentration decrease, photosynthesis rate only increase. (source: [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230054540_The_Effect_of_Oxygen_Concentration_on_Photosynthesis_in_Higher_Plants), [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00387501), [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1399-3054.1966.tb07046.x/abstract) and [this](http://phys.org/news/2011-02-oxygen-air-limit-productivity.html))

This take place due to mainly [2 causes](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Warburg_effect&oldid=747271684#Plant_physiology): 1. O<sub>2</sub> work in  competitive way with CO<sub>2</sub> for binding with the enzyme [RuBisCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RuBisCO), the key enzyme for CO<sub>2</sub> fixation in plants. 2. And that induces photorespiration (in C<sub>3</sub> plants). (Wikipedia shows reference to [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=jTxfMQg38B4C&lpg=PA236&ots=5IiQLoTiSk&dq=RuBisCO%20warburg%20effect&pg=PA236&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=RuBisCO%20warburg%20effect&f=false)). (However [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1399-3054.1966.tb07046.x/abstract) old paper also tells other hypotheses)

---

***There are 2 type of responses*** in photosynthesis rate in at different O2 concentration in various plant species.

One group of plants ( known to bel [C<sub>3</sub> plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_carbon_fixation), those do not have any any CO<sub>2</sub> concentrating mechanism) ), is remarkably affected by O2 concentration; i.e. affected by Warburg effect in true sense.

Another group of plants ( known to be [C<sub>4</sub> plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4_carbon_fixation), those have a certain type of CO<sub>2</sub> concentrating mechanism); does not significantly get affected by O<sub>2</sub>. I.e. doesn't show the Warburg effect.
(see also : [table](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=wmj7CAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA246&ots=pdXDw6vtAu&dq=c3%20c4%20warburg%20effect&pg=PA246#v=onepage&q=c3%20c4%20warburg%20effect&f=false)).

---

By the way, It seems photosynthesis would increase than normal  if we could make the environment "completely oxygen-free" but other parameters same. (due to elimination of O<sub>2</sub>inhibition) But I could not find any report about such "completely oxygen-free" conditions; and seemingly it is not possible because while doing photosynthesis; some  of the evolving oxygen molecules will pass through the cytoplasm; some will move in the intercellular space, and few molecules will stay diffused in atmosphere around the plant. We can only decrease the concentration of O2

---

Also; Warburg effect is completely about photosynthesis rate. **It is not about plant's overall health**. Removal of O2 increase photosynthesis rate... it does **NOT** mean the plant would live healthiest in oxygen deprived condition

---

> Sources:
>
> 1. Fundamentals of Plant Physiology by Dr. V. K. Jain; revised edition; S. Chand Publications, New Delhi.
> 2. `*` Biochemistry/ Lubert Stryer/ 4th Edition/ W. H. Freeman and Co.